# Split a complex string into a list of classes using regular expressions and lambda in C#

Tags: c#, regex, lambda

Given the string "a:b,c", I would like to use regular expressions and lambda expressions in C# to split the string into a list of classes so that I return the following.

```
{
    Column1: "a",
    Column2: "b",
},
{
    Column1: "a",
    Column2: "c",
}
```

In other words, I want to repeat the value before the colon for every comma separated value behind the colon. In SQL this would be the equivalent of doing a cross join where Column1 is the left side of the join and Column2 is the right side.

I have most of the code, including the regular expressions, but I cannot get the second `select` to project the `split` of the comma separated values into new classes. Instead, my code effectively returns the following.

```
{
    Column1: "a",
    Column2: [
        "b",
        "c"
    ]
}
```

Here's my code, as it stands.

```
public class MyClass {
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
}

List<MyClass> mc = "a:b,c"
    .Select(a => new { Column1 = new Regex(@"[a-z]+(?=\:)").Match(a).Value), Column2s = new Regex(@"(?<=\:)[a-z]+(,[a-z]+)*").Match(a).Value })
    .Select(b => new MyClass { Column1 = b.Column1, Column2 = b.Column2s.Split(',') })
    .ToList();
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Dukeling, thanks for catching that.

Comment: What do you do about field values that contain `:` or `,`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string input = "a:b,c";

int colon = input.IndexOf(':');
string left = input.Substring(0, colon);
string right = input.Substring(colon + 1);

List<MyClass> result = right.Split(',')
                            .Select(x => new MyClass
                            {
                                Column1 = left,
                                Column2 = x,
                            })
                            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

For sure exists others workarounds to your problem. You can try this one:

```
    [Test]
    public void ATest()
    {
        const string TestValue = "a:b,c";

        string valueForColumnA = new Regex(@"[a-z]+(?=\:)").Match(TestValue).Value;
        string setForColumnB = new Regex(@"(?<=\:)[a-z]+(,[a-z]+)*").Match(TestValue).Value;
        var target = setForColumnB.Split(',')
            .Select(item => new MyClass { Column1 = valueForColumnA, Column2 = item })
            .ToList();

        Assert.AreEqual(target[0].Column1, "a");
        Assert.AreEqual(target[0].Column2, "b");

        Assert.AreEqual(target[1].Column1, "a");
        Assert.AreEqual(target[1].Column2, "c");
    }
```

Probably are better solutions without using regular expressions (in terms of performance) but, if you specify this as a requirement, this solution works.